# delaying code in jquery

Tags: jquery, delay, addclass, effect

i'm trying to add and remove some classes in sequence, with a delay in between.
i've got several list-items of which i'd like to sequencially change the background color, when another button is clicked (kind of like a flashing-effect).

```
$("#changeclasses").click(function () {
    $(".listitem1").addClass("yellow");
    $(".listitem1").removeClass("yellow");   
    $(".listitem2").addClass("yellow");
    $(".listitem2").removeClass("yellow");      
});
```

i tried the following but obviously it didn't work :/

```
$("#changeclasses").click(function () {
    $(".listitem1").addClass("yellow").delay(200);
    $(".listitem1").removeClass("yellow").delay(200);  
    $(".listitem2").addClass("yellow").delay(200);
    $(".listitem2").removeClass("yellow");        
});
```

any help would be great! thank you.

Comment: have you tried chaining your actions instead of seperate ones such as: `$(".listitem1").addClass("yellow").delay(200).removeClass("yellow").delay(200);`

Comment: mh. this doesn't seem to work. but the "settimeout" answer works fine.

Comment: ahh.. haven't been into jquery for a while, sorry. i remember that there was a way of doing it by "chaining" similar to what I did above, but apparently it isn't exactly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should consider using `setTimeout`

```
$("#changeclasses").click(function () {
    $(".listitem1").addClass("yellow");
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".listitem1").removeClass("yellow"); }, 200);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".listitem2").addClass("yellow") }, 400);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".listitem2").removeClass("yellow") }, 600);      
});
```

Comment: thanks alot! .. just for interest — why is settimeout better? plainly because it works? :)

Comment: `delay` can be used within one jquery object, so I don't think there is a way to omit using `setTimeout` here :) besides, `setTimeout` is exactly what jquery's `delay` does